# Como verificar se uma tabela existe em MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, tabela-banco-de-dados

Eu já achei varias formas na internet, porem nenhuma do jeito que eu queria.

Eu gostaria de um método em java para em que se verifica se uma tabela existe ou não no banco de dados, caso exista retorne `TRUE` senão retorne `FALSE`.

Grato desde já.

Obs: não vou colocar nenhum código, pois os que achei na internet eram muito extensos e executavam mais do que eu queria(apenas testar se existe ou não).

Comment: Pensando rapidamente em um método é muito fácil basta você fazer um select na tabela caso contenha linhas na mesma isso será verdadeiro retorne true se não false. public static boolean verificaSeExite() {} public boolean verificaSeExite(){}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode rodar uma consulta SQL no MySQL usando [show tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/show-tables.html) e verificar se a *query* retornou algum resultado para a consulta usando Java (o que gera os códigos mais extensos).

```
show tables like `MinhaTabela`
```

Ou usar os [metadados (Java)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html) disponíveis:

```html
/**
 *
 *  abre a conexão com o banco de dados
 */
Connection conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USUÁRIO, SENHA);

/**
 *
 *  acessa os metadados do banco de dados
 */
DatabaseMetaData metadados = conexao.getMetaData();

/**
 *
 *   verificar se a tabela existe
 */
ResultSet tabela = metadados.getTables(null, null, "MinhaTabela", null);

/**
 *
 *  condição, caso a tabela exista
 */
if (tabela.next()) {
  /**
   *
   *  faça algo se a tabela existir
   */
}
```

Comment: Olá, poderia me explicar um pouco sobre a função `next()` ??

Comment: Essa função serve para mover a leitura do scanner em Java. Por padrão, os dados do scanner são retornados em forma de tokens, o que gera espaços em branco. A função `next()` vai retornar o primeiro token não-vazio (true), que é o resultado da consulta aos metadados ou "o próximo resultado  da consulta". Se não existir nenhum resultado, retorna false, por isso o `if`