# Criar banco de dados Mysql em tempo de execução

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação de cadastro em Java e preciso que essa aplicação ao ser executada verifique se existe a base de dados, caso ocorra de a base não existir ela cria essa base e suas tabelas para que a aplicação possa inserir os dados.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Answer (score 1):

Tirando como base das respostas [Como verificar se uma tabela existe em MySQL](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/130965/60376) e de outra no [SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11909597/8353154).

```
// abre a conexão com o banco de dados
Connection conexao = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USUÁRIO, SENHA);

// acessa os metadados do banco de dados
DatabaseMetaData metadados = conexao.getMetaData();

// erificar se a tabela existe
ResultSet tabela = metadados.getTables(null, null, "MinhaTabela", null);

// condição, caso a tabela exista
if (tabela.next()) {
    // faça algo se a tabela existir
} else {
    // faça algo se a não tabela existir
    criarTabela();
}
```

Função para criar a tabela

```
private void criarTabela() throws SQLException {
    String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MinhaTabela"
            + "  (id              INTEGER(10),"
            + "   nome            VARCHAR(80),"
            + "   email           VARCHAR(80))";

    Statement stmt = conexao.createStatement();
    stmt.execute(sqlCreate);
}
```

**Obs** devido a eu estar em um computador totalmente despreparado, não pode ser realizado teste.